# Continuous Rotation

Tags: programming, motor, continuous-servo

I was wondering how can I make a Servo rotate continuously by using an Arduino code.
I looked through several forums and websites already, but all of them just show how to make it run by changing the servo physically, I wanted to be able to do it with just the code.

Thanks for your help already!

Comment: Please be detailed on what kind of servo you use? Analog or digital servo?

Comment: Can you please be more specific! As @dpw asks, what type of servo is it? Do you have any web links to this servo? What have you tried so far? Please add links to the forums visited. What do you mean by "all of them just show how to make it run by changing the servo physically"?

Comment: As long as you use a continuous rotation servo, you can use the standard Servo library on Arduino: `0` will stop the servo, `90` will make it go full speed forward, `-90` will make it go full speed backward.

Answer (score 3):

The objective you seek will require a servo that has been manufactured to be continuously rotatable. The locations you've found are for those with extra servos who might not want to purchase a slightly more expensive servo and might want to use what they have on hand.

Once you have such a servo, self-modified or purchased as such, your code will work as you suggest. You should be able to easily locate the necessary code to operate a 360 degree servo using current libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, a servo is rotating 180 degrees because it has a drag  inside on gears who stop rotating continuously (360 degrees).
To make a servo to rotate 360 degrees, you need to buy a new servo or modify this one.